# How to make sub_folder in alfresco using Content Management Interoperability Services api?

Tags: alfresco

How to make sub_folder in alfresco using Content Management Interoperability Services api,I am able to create folder in alfresco but I want to make sub folder inside this folder but,not geeting any idea how to do that,so please help me..thankyou in advance

This is my method for creating folder :

```
public void folder(){       
     //here creating sub folder inside cmis parentfolder
     Map<String, Object> folderProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     folderProperties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:folder");
     folderProperties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "fotball_8");

     CmisObject newFolder1 =lSession.getObjectByPath(rootFolder.getPath()+ "/" + "fotball_9");
     Folder newFolder = rootFolder.createFolder(folderProperties);
     LOGGER.info("Your folder is created:"+folderProperties);

     //now checking that Folder is created or not
     ItemIterable<CmisObject> children = rootFolder.getChildren();
     LOGGER.info("Now finding the following objects in the root folder:-");
     for (CmisObject o : children) {
            LOGGER.info(o.getName());
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your code ?

Comment: this is my method for creating  folder

Comment: You seem to already have working code for creating a folder. Why not call something very similar on the new folder to create the sub folder?

Comment: Gagravarr ,really i tried but i am not able to create subfolder.....if u have some example then please give me...

Answer (score 1):

Change to following code.

```
 CmisObject newFolder1 =lSession.getObjectByPath(rootFolder.getPath()+ "/" + "fotball_9");
 Folder newFolder = newFolder1.createFolder(folderProperties);
```

You are calling create folder using rootFolder now you need to call it using newFolder1

Comment: What line ? What object is null (you can find it with debug) ?